# Table definition to a variable

Tags: mysql, variables, definition

I want to assign table definition of particular table in to a variable.

I know that, `SHOW CREATE TABLE tab_name` will return table definition.
I want to assign that definition to a variable.
eg: I have a variable named `@tab_def`.
When I execute `SELECT @tab_def` I want to get table definition like

```
 CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customerNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customerName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contactLastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contactFirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postalCode` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `salesRepEmployeeNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creditLimit` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerNumber`),
  KEY `salesRepEmployeeNumber` (`salesRepEmployeeNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `customers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`salesRepEmployeeNumber`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employeeNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: You cannot assign result of show to a variable. If you want to build such a variable do so from information_schema.tables,information_schema.columns etc (see manual for more on information schema)

Comment: If you can tell us why you wish to do this we may be able to suggest an alternative.